# CR Community Goes to GitHub!

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

***Code Review.** A community that learns as it grows, and grows as it learns.*

[weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge) projects are a huge opportunity to learn from each other. As individual coding *marathons*, these projects are *fun*.

Here's the proposition: each [weekend-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge) project gets a dedicated GitHub repository, where the **canonical implementation** comes to life; each "winning proposal" for a weekend challenge becomes an ongoing community project.

And then we can have other such *community projects*, like we could write an API for SE Chat, or whatever *we as a community*, decide we should come up with.

It's possible such an idea would not be possible because it would/could affiliate StackExchange with GitHub and we don't intend to instigate that. I wonder if, if not *officially* SE-stamped, we *can* do this.

When someone has code to commit, the modified class(es) can (should!) be posted on the main site to be reviewed by anyone; the CR question would need to be Community Wiki, and link to the GitHub repository, and the code that isn't the OP's code should be in a quote block.

Any other ideas? Objections? Suggestions? Unicorns?

Comment: I don't take part in the weekend challenges, but theorically speaking, this is a great idea!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the paragraph "When someone has code to commit", if you mean what I think you mean, why not only say in any post "I plan to add this to github [link]"? Why the need to make it a CW question?

Comment: @codesparkle: Oh, I thought you were killing that tag. :-) Looks like it was supposed to be the Meta tag, not the main site's nonexistent one.

Comment: @Jamal shouldn't this be wikified?

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/402/could-code-review-be-used-to-create-a-community-library

Comment: What should the naming scheme be for repositories we create?  Right now for the "Weekend Challenges" I'm thinking to create simple repository names, such as `Sudoku Solver` with maybe an indication of the language used included in the name.

Comment: @syb0rg let's try that. Also I'd like to know if we can use the CR beta-logo on there...

Comment: **ongoing community project**. Rock-paper-scissors? Are you sure?

Comment: @AseemBansal **canonical implementation** - damn right! Check this out: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/science/rock-paper-scissors.html?_r=0

Answer (score 5):

### Please visit the [GitHub Code Review Community page](http://codereviewcommunity.github.io/) for more information on joining the group.

**Please state what language/team(s) you would like to be added to when you open an issue.** If your reputation on <strike>Code Review</strike> any StackExchange site is *greater than or equal* to **2000**, you will be added to the "Admin" team automatically. Please be patient with the processing of your request.

Keep in mind that the reputation requirements for admins is subject to change at the decision of the group owners, and that the community page is still in development.

---

### Questions I need answered by the community

1. Should I keep or abolish "teams" (related: [access permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions))?  They seem to be more of a pain then an organization tool to sort the code by language.=

---

I have some points to make on this subject:

- How the Code Review Community is going to use GitHub is still being debated and decided.  If you want to be part of that process, I recommend you join the "[The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)" (Code Review's chatroom).
- This is *not* aimed to take you away from the Code Review site.  The purpose of reviewing code is intended to find and fix mistakes overlooked in the initial development phase, improving both the overall quality of software and the developers' skills.  **We want to make this reviewed code available to all, as an example of what code should look like.**  This is a way we can do that.
- This is a gateway to community projects (something I am really looking forward to).  As @retailcoder put in his post, one project suggestion is to take up and maintain a Stack Exchange chat API (the old unofficial API [has gone stagnant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat), and Stack Exchange does not provide an official API for chat yet).  There are other possibilities as well, we just need to decide on a community what to work on together.

Comment: I think *how GitHub is going to be used* should be debated & discussed right here on meta :)